# Score Multiplier in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an application that adds one to the score whenever you tap anywhere on the view. I would like to have a score multiplier that states that whenever the user is tapping faster his or her score will not just increment by one, but by a larger amount depending on how fast and/or how long they have been tapping. I've done a good bit of Googling but I have yet to find anything. Thanks in advance

Comment: Add a [`UIGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer) to your view. Every time the view is touched, record the time and compare against previous touch, then decide the multiplier according to the time interval.

Answer (score 0):

Without further examples its hard to actually give you help, here is a stab

```
static let multiplier = 1000

struct Player {

  var score: Int
  var displayScore: Int {
    return score * multiplier
  }

}

var player = Player(score: 1)
print(player.displayScore) // 1000
player.score += 1
print(player.displayScore) // 2000
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't explain it very well. Say a user had just started tapping on the view, as of now every time they tap 1 is added to their score. What I would like to happen is say they started tapping and continued to tap steadily, their score would start incrementing at an increasing rate. For example, if they had been tapping for ten seconds their score would increment the first time at 1.01, then 1.02, then 1.03 and so on until they stopped tapping and then the multiplier would decrease slowly until it gets back to 1. Similar games that use multipliers are Cookie Clicker or Bitcoin Billionare